# Easy way to create buffer in QGIS 2?

Tags: vector, buffer, qgis-2

In the old version of QGIS creating buffer was a relatively complicated task.

Basically you had to save your layer as a new one with metric cylinder CRS in order to calculate distance correctly.

If you have not done it the calculation was off. The main cause was the proportion distortion of the WGS/84 CRS.

Is there a faster way in the 2.18.11 QGIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the 2.18.11 QGIS version there is a easy way to calculate buffers.

This option is in build in the MMQGIS plugin  [image].

Once you have the QGIS plugin you have the option to create buffer [image]

When you are making the buffer take care to choose the right distance unit for the buffer radius[image]

This is a great tool from the QGIS  Las Palmas developers!