# The buffer is covering unnecessary area of the polygon it was made from in QGIS

Tags: polygon, buffer

Consider a polygon that represents the area of New York State [image]

I made a 125KM buffer from this layer [image]

My problem is that the new buffer layer is covering the source polygon and I need only the outer borderlines of the 125KM radius. I need it as a new line layer for future work, so just changing the fill of the polygon into 100% transparent will not work [image].

How can I display only a line layer that is located in a distance of 125KM from the borderline of the New York State polygon?

Comment: The easiest way for showing just the outline of the buffered polygon is to edit the rendering styles of that layer and remove the fill.

Comment: This is the correct output of a buffer operation. If you want to isolate the "outside" you just need to Erase (or Union Or Intersect) the source from the result.

Comment: Yes, but I only need the outline border not the all of the area between the source polygon and the new one

Comment: You could convert the buffer polygon to a line with `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to Lines`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time looking into it and found a pretty nice solution.

When I made a new buffer layer in [MMQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251692/a-easy-way-to-create-buffer-in-qgis) it's making a new layer with an extra area respectively to the radius we defined.

So, if we have only the outer line of the buffer we will get the borderline we needed.

In the Vector tool bar there is an option to transfer a polygon layer into a line layer that represented only the outer line of the polygon [image]

We need to be sure that we are choosing the right layer and some other layer from our project [image]
Once we have done thus steps we will have a temporary layer which is recommended to save as a layer.
It's also recommended to measuring the radius, just for being sure that our result makes sense [image]

We cannot be one hundred accurate in this kind of hand measurement, so small a deviation of 880 meters, or 0.58%, it is probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

If the aim is to show only the borderline of a polygon there is no need to convert the polygon layer into line layer. It is enough to make polygon fill transparent by adjusting the rendering styles.

Here is a polygon that is created by buffering Colorado

[image]

For showing just the borderline make QGIS to use transparent fill

[image]

Comment: ... or change the fill style from `Solid` to `No Brush`.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem : "*My problem is that the new buffer layer is covering the source polygon*"

If you need only the area outside, you could use the following tool "**Symmetrical difference**" in the QGIS geoalgorithms. After that, you could convert this polygon to a line layer

[image: Tool]

Configuration :

[image: Toolbox]

Result with no overlay :

[image: Result]

Then if needed :

[image: Convert tool]

And a conversion just for the line you need (delete the other one) :

[image: line]